# MatterJS allow bodies to pass through yet still trigger collision

Tags: matter.js

I want certain rigid bodies to be able to pass through eachother, i.e. no collision response. Though I still want the collision to *detect*, and trigger an event for collisionsActive: `Events.on('collisionActive')` so that I can execute some code when they collide with eachother.

```
Events.on(engine, 'collisionActive', (event) => {
  for (const body of event.pairs) {
    if (body.a collides with body.b) doSomeStuff(body.a, body.b)
  }
});
```

These rigid bodies sit on 'floors' or 'platforms', so they need to collide with these walls or floors, but pass through other bodies.
One option is to give the bodies a `category` in the `collisionFilter` but this doesn't seem to trigger the collisionActive event.

What can I do here?

Answer (score 2):

When you create a body you can pass the option `isSensor` as **true**, that way the body will pass through anything and will trigger the collision event

```
{ 
 isSensor:true 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by manually going over the Bodies and comparing their bounds using `Bounds.contains`.

```
if (Bounds.contains(bodyA.bounds, bodyB.position)) doSomeStuff()
```